# Google analytics not sending with _gaTracker variable?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics, jquery-events

I'm creating a custom event for Google Analytics. It works on sites where GA is installed normally.

So I have this working fine:

```
 jQuery("a[href^='tel:']").click(function(event){
        if (typeof ga !== 'undefined') {
                ga('send', 'event', 'Contact', 'Phone', 'Click');
        }
 });
```

^^ This Adds an event to analytics whenever a phone number is tracked on the site.

I have a problem though, where Analytics is added to the site by a WordPress plugin (namely, Monster insights). That plugin used the __gaTracker instead of ga.

So. I have tried both of the following with no luck:

```
__gaTracker('send', 'event', 'Contact', 'Phone', 'Click');
```

and

```
var ga = __gaTracker;
ga('send', 'event', 'Contact', 'Phone', 'Click');
```

Still nothing is working -- I'm not getting any console errors either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `window.GoogleAnalyticsObject` to get the active GA object